# is it possible to show admob interstitial when user click the item of listview?

Tags: android, listview, admob

I have a listview on my app.i want to show an admob interstitial ads when user click the item of listview .is it possible? if possible please give me code...

Comment: ok sir how can I do it ?

Comment: i am a beginner of android app development and also a student of electrical works

Answer (score 0):

Of course, It is possible just show your interstitial ad in listview.setOnItemclicklistener